# Contract deployment costs

Tags: contract-deployment, gas-price

I have a contract that when deployed to Sepolia costs ~550K gas to deploy:

[image]

current gas rate on the mainnet is <50 gwei:

[image]

yet, when I try to deploy to the mainnet, I am declined on not having enough funds for a transaction that is around 30% higher than I expected.

Expected to pay around 550,000 * 50 * 10^-9 = 0.0275 ETH

In practice, tx cost is 0.31 ETH

[image]

Can someone explain?

Comment: In the screenshot for the mainnet transaction that you've attached of the wallet, you're checking the **Low** gas option i.e., **47 gwei**. That's what you've used to calculate the expected tx cost as **0.0275 ETH**. But in actual when executing the transaction from the code, it might be considering the **Market** gas option, which should be significantly higher as compared to **Low** gas option, based on network congestion and demand, resulting in the actual tx cost to be **0.31 ETH**.